# Maximum volume of open top box without calculus

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

A $5\times6$ piece of paper has squares of side-length $x$ cut from each of its corners, such that folding up the sides will create a box with no top. Find the value of $x$ that maximizes the volume of the open-top box without using calculus.
I got the volume of the open top box is $V(x)=(5-2x)(6-2x)x=4x^3-22x^2+30x.$ From here, how to find $x?$

Comment: If you are not going to use calculus, then graph/plot the volume function and visualize for which value of $x$, your volume graph attains its maximum. The only difference is calculus will give you an exact answer, while graph will give you an approximate one.

Comment: https://www.themathdoctors.org/max-and-min-of-a-cubic-without-calculus/